# Insert multiple data (List) in MySQL using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying it from last 2 hour i dont know what is going wrong. also let me know how could i test if the connection is successfull or not.. it is for now.. but still i wanted to know..

---

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?)'

My code:

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/medicinedb";
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "";
static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

public boolean saveMedicine(List<MedicineName> medicineName) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);

        //STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        //STEP 4: Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        for (MedicineName element : medicineName) {

            String sql;
            sql = " insert into medicinename (name, pgurl)" + " values 
            ( ?, ?)";
            System.out.println(conn);

            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStmt.setString(1, element.getName());
            preparedStmt.setString(2, element.getPgurl());
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }

        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you try with this `sql = "insert into medicinename (name, pgurl)  values (?, ?)";`

Comment: same error......@YCF_L

Comment: what is the type of `name and pgurl` in your database

Comment: You are putting the sql into a prepared statement (preparedStmt) but attempting to execute the other statement (stmt). This seems wierd

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using Statement and Prepared statement. You are performing operations with Statement. Thus it does not have value. Remove the Statement

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

And do the following

```
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, element.getName());
        preparedStmt.setString(2, element.getPgurl());
        //stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        preparedStmt .executeUpdate(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You mix between your `stm` and `preparedStmt`, you have to execute `preparedStmt` and not `stm`.
2. Another thing when you want to executing multiple statements as one unit, its good to work with Statement Batching instead for example :

`PreparedStatement preparedStmt;
String sql;
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
for (MedicineName element : medicineName) {

    sql = "insert into medicinename (name, pgurl) values (?, ?)";
    System.out.println(conn);

    preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStmt.setString(1, element.getName());
    preparedStmt.setString(2, element.getPgurl());
    preparedStmt.addBatch(sql);
}
preparedStmt.executeBatch();
conn.commit();`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 String sql = "insert into medicinename (name, pgurl) values (?, ?)";
                  PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                  preparedStmt.setString (1, element.getName());
                  preparedStmt.setString (2, element.getPgurl());
                  preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

you should delete executeUpdate(sql); to executeUpdate();
```